# How can I check if headTitle is already used in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to check if headTitle is already used?

To avoid appending or overwriting existing title, which was set earlier in parent views/layout.

Thanks ;)

**Update**

Example:

```
$this->headTitle('First title'); // index.phtml
$this->headTitle('Second title'); // some-nested-tpl.phtml
```

Check whether First title is set and assign Second if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check the content of headTitle and if it's the default then write something else like:

```
if($this->headTitle() == '<title></title>') {
  $this->headTitle('foo')
}
```

Or write yourself a view-helper to safe yourself some writing time and have a function like

```
$this->headTitleIfEmpty('foo');
```

which does the above, so you have a short tag in your templates.